# My animations arent working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

im trying to fade in a video after 5 seconds, then fade out a video after pressing a button, which then scrolls the page to the next section.

At the next section, it should animate some divs, then....pressing the button to go to the next section, fade out animates the previously animated divs, THEN goes to the next section.

The 3rd scroll button doesn't work at all.

Only the last 2 scroll buttons work....I can't figure out why only these last 2, and not the first 3 week.

NOTE: Id also like to kill the scrollbar on the page, and have the page navigated via the scroll buttons.  Here is my code that is giving me trouble:

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

//Kill Page Scrollbar    
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'height': '100%'
});


//animate the registration video fading in
$('#Video').fadeTo(3000, 1); 
//Make scrollbutton clickable
$('.ScrollButton_White1').click(function(){
//Fade Video out
     $('#Video').fadeTo(3000, 0), (function(){
//define the variable "diamonds"
    var diamonds = $('#PresenterContainer').children()
//animate the scrolling of the page down to the anchor point//                                     
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#PresenterContainer_AnchorPoint").offset().top
    }, 5000,
                            function() {
         diamonds.show();

                          });
     });
});

<!--scroll button 2-->               
$('.ScrollButton_Gold1').click(function(){

         diamonds.hide();   

$('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#YouAskedForIt_AnchorPoint").offset().top
                    }, 5000
 );
});


<!--scroll button 3-->
$('.ScrollButton_White3').click(function(){

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#ReturnChampion_AnchorPoint").offset().top
                    }, 5000
);                                                                  
});

<!--scroll button 4-->
$('.ScrollButton_Gold1').click(function(){

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#YouAskedForIt_AnchorPoint").offset().top
                    }, 5000);                  


                 });

<!--scroll button 5-->
$('.ScrollButton_Gold2').click(function(){

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#WhatYouWillLearn_AnchorPoint").offset().top
                    }, 5000);                  


                 });

<!--animate presenter diamond buttons-->
<!--$(window).scroll(function(event) {


            <!--$('#Diamond_DarrenHardy').addClass('animate_rf');
            <!--$('#Diamond_RobertKiyosaki').addClass('animate_rf');-->



    <!--});

<!--end jquery script-->    
});
 </script>
```

Comment: It seems your are creating some thing on fly, try using live event.

Comment: -2- and -4- both use the same selector `.ScrollButton_Gold1`. `diamonds` is local to -1-, but -2- tries to use it. You shoud see an error in your console. Exercise more care in writing/checking your code.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a typo in your code

```
$('#Video').fadeTo(3000, 0), (function() {
        //define the variable "diamonds"
        var diamonds = $('#PresenterContainer').children()
        //animate the scrolling of the page down to the anchor point//
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#PresenterContainer_AnchorPoint").offset().top
            }, 5000,
            function() {
                diamonds.show();

            });
    });
```

At `$('#Video').fadeTo(3000, 0), (function() {` If you are looking to use the callback functionality of fadeTo it should be

```
$('#Video').fadeTo(3000, 0, function() {
        //define the variable "diamonds"
        var diamonds = $('#PresenterContainer').children()
        //animate the scrolling of the page down to the anchor point//
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#PresenterContainer_AnchorPoint").offset().top
            }, 5000,
            function() {
                diamonds.show();

            });
    });
```

Comment: my code still isnt behaving the way i want it, even with that edit.  Now it animates the scroll as soon as the page loads....wasnt looking for that

Comment: That code I updated should have gone inside the click handler. Could you please put your code in a JSFiddle

Comment: You have not added your html and you have replaced the wrong section of code from my example